# how to display the results of a query in a listbox and how to use the multiple values that are selected in VBA in access

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access-2010

First of all thanks for your help regarding my previous question.
I have been trying to develop the access DB  for storing the employee details. I need to get details about an employee regarding which department he belongs to and which job he does and which team he belongs to. the above three are like service stream and team in my example.I have used combo box for getting these values as user inputs now based on the above three filters I need to display all the employees who belong to the respective team. I have written a query if this to work in the list box which displays the employee name details how ever when I run the form nothing appears in this field.
the query that I used is

```
SELECT [Team Members].Name
FROM [Team Members]
WHERE ((([Forms]![TestForm]![TeamComboBox])=[Team Members]![Team]) 
    AND (([Forms]! [TestForm]![StreamComboBox])=[Team Members]![Stream]) 
    AND (([Forms]![TestForm]![ServiceComboBox])=[Team Members]![Service]));
```

where Team Members is the name of the table and Name ,Team,Stream and Service  are the names of thefields and TeamComboBox,StreamComboBox and ServiceComboBox are the combo box whose values I need to filter the names of all the employee.

Also I have considered that all the fields in the table that is name ,team,stream and servi together form a primary key
Could somebody suggest me what is the mistake in this query?
However if I press f5 then the values display

Could you please suggest me what should be done.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is most likely nothing wrong with your query per say, rather you may not be using the correct syntax in Access for it to properly pull into the list box. It has been some time since I coded something like this in an Access database, but I remember vaguely needing to dynamically add items to a static list of available entries in VBA in order to accomplish a similar goal to what you are trying to achieve.

Take a look at the [tutorial linked in this answer](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d62235ff-ced9-489e-8f9d-d2ad6294e46f/how-to-populate-a-listbox-with-data-pulled-from-an-access-table?forum=isvvba) as it details several ways of using VBA to do what you are trying to do.

You should be able to use that .AddItem command along with your existing query to populate the items you need. Good Luck!